# Polarity Detection on Array Charging System for Autonomous Robot

Tags: battery-charging, charging, reverse-polarity, polarity, autonomous

### Array Charging Concept

I recently became interested in designing a charging system for an autonomous robot. The key requirement is that precise orientation of the robot is not necessary during charging, and wireless charging is not an option. The concept involves creating an array of conductive metal pads on the wall, where the robot can drive into using spring contacts. Following that, the appropriate pads can be activated to charge the robot.

[image: Array Charging System]

---

### Sensing pads & polarity

I have difficulty in defining a good method for activating the correct contact pads and sensing the required polarity for charging. I came across the following circuit which uses a precision diode circuit to convert the battery inputs to a unipolar analog voltage which can be read by a microcontroller to control the DPDT switch.

I see how this circuit would work for two contacts. However, I have difficulty in understanding how this circuit could be extended for multiple metal contact pads. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwtQaB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Thanks in advance